# Computable function example

Tags: logic, computability

Suppose $p(x)\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$. How can we show that the function
$b\to$ the least non-negative integer root of $p(x) - b$
is computable (if there is no such root, then the function is undefined)?

One thing I thought of was trying to define the function in terms of a GCD operator or sgn function to show that we have something that is p.r. which is then computable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to work too hard. Let $p(x) \in \mathbb Z[x]$ if $a \in \mathbb Z$ is a root of $p(x)$ then $a \mid c$ where $c$ is the constant term of $p(x)$, this is the [rational root theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem). So to find the least positive integer root it suffices to enumerate the divisors of the constant term, which is surely computable and pick the smallest one that satisfies $p(x)$. If no such root exists return *null* or whatever the fail character is.